# When I use a sklearn parallel module "from cdnmf_fast import _update_cdnmf_fast", its parallelization is not working

Tags: scikit-learn, cython, ipython-parallel, matrix-factorization, nmf

(This is my first time of asking a question, if you think the tags or description have something wrong, please tell me, thank you!)

I'm doing a work on `Matrix Factorization` and use the module `sklearn.decomposition.nmf`
the module uses another module
`from sklearn.decomposition.cdnmf_fast import _update_cdnmf_fast`
This module is from file `cdnmf_fast.so`
You can check out its source code on this website
[/sklearn/decomposition/cdnmf_fast.pyx](https://searchcode.com/file/115659726/sklearn/decomposition/cdnmf_fast.pyx)
We can see that it uses C-language and "with nogil:", so I think it must have used parallelization.
So I write a similar code to test it as follows:

```
from sklearn.decomposition.cdnmf_fast import _update_cdnmf_fast
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
M = 3
X = zeros((M,M), dtype="float64")
U = ones((M,M), dtype="float64")
V = np.arange(M*M).reshape(M,M).astype("float64")
permutation = np.arange(M)
print X
print U
print V
print permutation
x = _update_cdnmf_fast(X,U,V,permutation)
print X
```

The expected result is X=X+V-W*U=0+V-0=V. However, the result is strange and it's far more slowly than np.dot().
Then I change this code into normal python code, not parallelization code.
The result is the same as before.
So I'm sure that its parallelization is not working.
Because it's using X while it's changing X, the result is of course wrong.
I don't know why its parallelization is not working.
Is it due to the bug of the module or the method of the way I import?

Actually, this makes me concerned when I use the sklearn.decomposition.nmf module, I'm not sure when I use this module, whether its parallelization is also not working or not. So I want to know how it makes the parallelization work.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `with nogil` doesn't make something parallel, it only releases the GIL so that parallelization is possible (e.g. could call that function from two python threads and they could run simultaneously)

Comment: @chrisb is right. In this case the function doesn't look like it uses multiple threads. `np.dot` is generally pretty quick and probably parallel.